# Regex match double quote which does not follow slash character

Tags: java, regex

I have string like this:

> "abcd\" efg\" hi" jklm"

I want to get sub string between two first characters `"`, which is not `\"`
For example, in the above string, I want to get `abcd\" efg\" hi`
Currently, I replace `\"` by another character, then use the regex `"([^"]*)"` to extract the sub string between two first characters `"`. Is there any way to use regex directly without replacing `\"` by another character.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
[^\\]?"(.*?[^\\])"
```

**Explanation:**

```
[^\\]?   match an optional single character which is not backslash
"(.*?    match a quote followed by anything (non-greedy)
[^\\])"  match a quote preceded by anything other than backslash
```

This regex will match the least content between an opening quote and closing quote which does not have a backslash.

[**Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/dE1zF5/2)